# Maximum tip calculator - naive solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am working through a Geekforgeeks practice question. I have come up with a naive recursive solution to the "maximum tip calculator" problem.

The problem definition is:

> Restaurant recieves N orders.  If Rahul takes the ith order, gain
>   $A[i]. If Ankit takes this order, the tip would be $B[i] One order
>   per person. Rahul takes max X orders. Ankit takes max Y orders. 
>   X + Y >= N. Find out the maximum possible amount of total tip money
>   after processing all the orders.
>
> Input:
>
> The first line contains one integer, number of test cases. The second
>   line contains three integers N, X, Y. The third line contains N
>   integers. The ith integer represents Ai. The fourth line contains N
>   integers. The ith integer represents Bi.
>
> Output: Print a single integer representing the maximum tip money they
>   would receive.

My Code and working sample:

```
def max_tip(N, A, B, X, Y, n= 0):

    if n == len(A) or N == 0:
        return 0

    if X == 0 and Y > 0: # rahul cannot take more orders
        return max(B[n] + max_tip(N - 1, A, B, X, Y - 1, n + 1), # ankit takes the order
                    max_tip(N, A, B, X, Y, n + 1))  # ankit does not take order
    elif Y == 0 and X > 0: # ankit cannot take more orders
        return max(A[n] + max_tip(N - 1, A, B, X - 1, Y, n + 1), # rahul takes the order
                    max_tip(N, A, B, X, Y, n + 1)) # rahul does not take order
    elif Y == 0 and X == 0: # neither can take orders
        return 0
    else:
        return max(A[n] + max_tip(N - 1, A, B, X - 1, Y, n + 1), # rahul takes the order
                B[n] + max_tip(N - 1, A, B, X, Y - 1, n + 1), #ankit takes the order
                max_tip(N, A, B, X, Y, n + 1)) # nobody takes the order

T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    nxy = [int(n) for n in input().strip().split(" ")]
    N = nxy[0]
    X = nxy[1]
    Y = nxy[2]

    A = [int(n) for n in input().strip().split(" ")]
    B = [int(n) for n in input().strip().split(" ")]

    print(max_tip(N, A, B, X, Y))
```

I've annotated my recursive call decisions. Essentially I extended the naive solution for 0-1 knapsack in another dimension two waiters, either one takes, the other takes, or both do not take the order depending on the orders left constraint.

The solution checker is complaining for the following testcase:

```
Input:
7 3 3
8 7 15 19 16 16 18
1 7 15 11 12 31 9

Its Correct output is:
110

And Your Code's Output is:
106
```

This confuses me because the optimal solution seems to be what my code is getting (19 + 16 + 18) + (7 + 15 + 31). The immediate issue seems to be that X + Y < N. My thought is my code should work for the case where X + Y < N as well.

What's going on?

Comment: Well, there's 4 ways to reach 110 (they all require 7 orders to be filled). And `7 3 3` clearly contradicts the statement that `X + Y >= N`. So I'm going to say that someone goofed up.

Comment: The practice question clearly states the constraint of `X + Y >= N` but your case doesn't meet it.  At that point I wouldn't expect the result to acceptable anyhow.  Besides, your question seems to be "Why is their code getting a different result than mine", in which case, it's hard to tell *how* their program was coded to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: In addition, many comments from the site seem to be complaining the test cases, so I would assume something over there isn't right.

Comment: Seems the problem definition is incorrect given the provided testcases. I'll assume my code is the optimal solution given the proper testcases

Comment: @Idlehands it's less "Why is their code getting a different result than mine" and more "why does this fail given the problem constraints and my solution?" From what I can tell, I have given an optimal (naive) solution of the problem. There are efficient O(n) top/down bottom/up DP solutions, but I think for a general naive recursive solution I hit the nail on the head. The testcase is provided by the author of the problem, so I can only assume he/she made an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

you are considering the case, where nobody takes the tip. But that case doesn't exist as X+Y >= n. This java code worked for me, have a look.

```
private static int getMaxTip(int x, int y, int n, int[] A, int[] B) {
     int[][] dp = new int[x + 1][y + 1];

     dp[0][0] = 0;
     for (int i = 1;i <= x;i++) {
         dp[i][0] = (i <= n) ? dp[i - 1][0] + A[i - 1] : dp[i - 1][0];
     }

     for (int i = 1;i <= y;i++) {
         dp[0][i] = (i <= n) ? dp[0][i - 1] + B[i - 1] : dp[0][i - 1];
     }

     for (int i = 1;i <= x;i++) {
         for (int j = 1;j <= y;j++) {
             if (i + j <= n) {
                 dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i - 1][j] + A[i + j - 1], dp[i][j - 1] + B[i + j - 1]);
             }
         }
     }

     int ans = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i = 0;i <= x;i++) {
         for (int j = 0;j <= y;j++) {
             if (i + j == n) {
                 ans = Math.max(ans, dp[i][j]);
             }
         }
     }
     return ans;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are considering a case when nobody takes the order that should not be considered as it is mentioned in the question that x+y>=n always.Removing that condition will work.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming, this is your source of question:
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-tip-calculator/0

Here is my solution written in Python that passed all case:
https://github.com/Madhu-Guddana/My-Solutions/blob/master/adhoc/max_tip.py

Explanation:
zip corresponding element of tips and create new array.
Sort the new array based on difference amount value for Rahul and Ankit,
Then we can safely consider the elements from 2 ends of the array, which ever end is giving more profit, add the value to count.

Comment: The main issue is that the invariant X + Y >= N must hold. If code is designed around this constraint, it will fail the creator's test case where X = 3, Y = 3, N = 7, and so 3 + 3 < 7. The premise of the problem is wrong, so any solution that solves the problem is also wrong.